# Both Dropzone with default file input

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

My project is in **Classic ASP** (though the problem relates mostly to an issue on the client). Previously, I used a third party (*SoftArtisans.FileUp*) to handle the uploaded files in the backend. And, this third party simply look for below tag and create a file object for us to handle.

```
<input type='file' name='myfile'>
```

So everything worked fine till now.

Wanting a better user experience for uploads at client, I now integrated **Dropzone** to handle multiple file uploads in front-end and **looking to NOT using Ajax way** and focused on existing form post but unfortunately, the file input is not passing with the form post like before (From page view-source: Dropzone moved the file input out of the form so it will not submit). so backend failed

The question is,

> Is there any way to add a hidden file input in addition to a dropzone
>   that contains the exact file uploaded in dropzone so I don't have to
>   change the backend much.

Means, If I upload a file via dropzone,
the same file should get in the hidden file upload, then I can make use of the hidden file in the backend.

What I tried,

1) From page view source, I realized Dropzone moved the file input out of the form, might be to prevent it from submission. so via Jquery, I moved it inside the form and got the file in the backend but its empty.

Comment: I would drop the classic ASP tag and replace with JavaScript as this is not really about ASP but a generic JS  & dropzone issue. Likely too few people saw this because of the tags.

Comment: Thanks @VanquishedWombat